# CKQuery gives me creatorUserRecordIDs with __defaultOwner__ CKDiscoverUserInfosOperation does not. How do I match the app's current user?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

In my app I have a list of objects where I want to show the name of the creator of the object.

(I know that the user will have to approve the discoverability. In my testing the current user ID already did.)

I used `CKDiscoverUserInfosOperation` to be efficient, but when I try to match up the `CKDiscoveredUserInfo` that are returned in the dictionary, the `CKRecordID` for records created by the current user is not the "__ defaultOwner __" `recordID` that I get back from the `CKQuery` that loaded my list.

How am I supposed to match these up?

It would be nice if the `CKQuery` operation and the `CKDiscoveredUserInfo` operations gave consistent `creatorUserRecordIDs` so that they can be compared. I think it would be wrong to have to special case the `defaultOwner` all over the place.

Comment: Not ideal; but why don't you create your own database with userIDs; so that you can cross reference and look and disclose what you like?

Comment: Discoverability of user info can change over time, so I don't want to manage my own database which would be against the spirit of the privacy setting. I just don't see the benefit of hiding the default owner's record id. The inconsistency is my main complaint since I do need to match the record ids when I go to show this in the UI.